# How to make a textarea scrollable with the mouse while still having the scrollbar removed?

Tags: html, css, scroll, textarea, scrollbar

As the title says, I think a scrollbar looks ugly. I removed it, but now it's not mouse-scrollable. I searched online and found nothing. Any help?

I tried to make it look cleaner, i expected the scrollbar to dissapear, which it did, but now the textarea is no longer scrollable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could effectively (and fairly cross-browser) be achieved with the following CSS:

```css
.element {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.element::webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work! Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but idk tbh

Comment: @lex_noob-for_now Would be great if you could provide a minimal way of reproducing where you are trying to use this so I could help more. Codepen might be a good place to put it.